# Connecting to a client cassandra from local

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I am trying to fetch data from cassandra that has been installed in AWS ec2.
When I run the following commands through pyspark, I am able to read from AWS,
However when I submit the same python file through spark-submit, I am fetching rdd from local. Can you suggest me where I am missing the configuration.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("testCassandra").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "#ec2ip#").set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

rdd = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tweettable", keyspace="twitterstorage", ).load().rdd
```

Comment: What IP are you trying to connect to?  It should be the node's public IP, which should be defined in your yaml as either your `listen_address` or `rpc_address`.

Comment: Yep, I have changed my yaml accordingly. And ya, I was able to solve this by passing --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=ip as arguments for the spark -submit.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by passing --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=ip as arguments for the spark -submit.